# How to use XSOData with sapui5

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide, hana-xs

I'm trying to configure XSOData service with my SAPUI5 application. simple odata service working fine. but when with XSOData i've some authentication problem. 
metadata file return me some sort of html with log on .. detail. I've found that it is because of XSOdata which has some issues. I'm using webide. some solutions are [hanatrial-auth-proxy](https://github.com/gregorwolf/hanatrial-auth-proxy) and [hana xs odata in webide](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/01/12/accessing-hana-xs-odata-in-web-ide-and-beyond/). I don't know how I can use that in webide.

[image]

[image: Meta Data]

[image: Destination Which I've configured]
Menifest.js file data source and model setting.

```
"dataSources": {
    "dlesContent": {
    "uri": "/destinations/dles/DLES/services/DLES_CONTENT.xsodata/NPS_CONTENT",
    "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
            "odataVersion": "2.0"
        }
        }
    },
"models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "dlesDLESdashboard.i18n.i18n"
            }
        },
        "dlesScore": {
            "dataSource": "dlesContent"
        }
    },
```

Comment: Can you paste some screenshots?

Comment: Can you try to log in to your hana system first and then run the application? If this succeeds, we can try to pass logged in username password to the oDatamodel so authentication proceeds automatically.

Comment: @john, remove the Entityset from the service url in your manifest, the url should be "uri": "/destinations/dles/DLES/services/DLES_CONTENT.xsodata"

Comment: I've now removed. but still error is there, Is there any thing I need to change in my destination? I mean way of authentication?